# Getting permissions to create a new folder using NSFileManager

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-lion

I'm having some problems trying to create a folder using NSFileManager in MacOS X. I'm creating the software in Lion if that changes anything.

Anyway. The program structure is something like this:

1. Fill in some fields.
2. Choose a folder using NSOpenPanel.
3. The program generates the name of the new folder from the fields.
4. Create a folder with that name in the chosen folder.

The code that is supposed to create the folder looks like this:

```c
NSString *name = [pnameField stringValue];
NSString *number = [self parseVerknr:[pnumberField stringValue]];
NSString *date = [pdateField stringValue];
NSString *folderName;

//Here I generate the folder name from some rules and stuffsies
//It ends up as something like: 13245_08 - cp. - name

NSOpenPanel *myPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

    myPanel.canChooseFiles = NO;
    myPanel.canChooseDirectories = YES;
    myPanel.canCreateDirectories = YES;

    [myPanel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result){

        if (result==NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton){

            NSFileManager *myManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

            NSError *merror;

            NSString *directoryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [myPanel.URL absoluteString], folderName];

            //Here the directory string looks like file://localhost/Users/username/Documents/folders/12345_09 - cp. - Koop
            directoryString = [directoryString substringFromIndex:6];
            //After it looks like: /localhost/Users/username/Documents/folders/12345_09 - cp. - Koop
            NSLog(@"directory: %@", directoryString);

            [myManager createDirectoryAtPath:directoryString withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&merror];

            NSLog(@"%@", [merror localizedDescription] );
        }

    }];
```

If I don't take the substring from index 6 I get a large error stack (tried to take it from 16 too which did the same). If I use the split string I get the following error:

```
You don’t have permission to save the file “localhost” in the folder “PK Bear”.
```

Since PK Bear is the name of my "hard drive" I'm guessing the program needs to get permission to access the hard drive. I just have no idea how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you're creating the path string. In particular, `-[NSURL absoluteString]` returns a string representation of the URL, not a filepath string. You should use NSURL and NSString's methods for working with paths. As explained in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/path), `-[NSURL path]` returns a path string suitable for inputting into NSFileManager methods.

Try this:

```
NSString *directoryString = [[myPanel.URL path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:folderName];
[myManager createDirectoryAtPath:directoryString withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&merror];
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks alot! I'll be sure to read up on the difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

You mix up (file-) URLs and (unix) paths.

You should create the directory path as follows:

```
NSString *directoryString = [[myPanel.URL path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:folderName];
if (! [myManager createDirectoryAtPath:directoryString withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&merror]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [merror localizedDescription]);
}
```

Key is using `path` instead of `absoluteString`.

Also: You cannot access the `merror` object unless the method that creates it returns `NO` (or whatever the error condition is).

You should never fiddle with single characters in path strings (as you did with `substringFromIndex:`). That's considered an advanced task in the face of unicode code points vs code fragments and combined characters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need to look better into using the NSError object, thanks for the pointer.